# Modified graph traversal

Tags: trees, graph-traversal

This question is most easy to describe as a modification of [that my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/358931/45576).

Suppose that question is solved as the following Python class:

```
class Traversal(object):
    # ...

    def next(self): # next node of the graph
        # ...
```

Now I want to modify the algorithm: Sometimes I want to traverse to the next *non*-preferred node.

```
class Traversal(object):
    # ...

    def next(self): # next node of the graph
        # ...

    def next2(self): # next non-preferred node of the graph
        # ...
```

How to modify the algorithm to implement `next2()`?

Note that both `next()` and `next2()` return a graph node and this node should be recorded not to be traversed again.

Sorry I cannot describe the real example where this problem appears, it would be too verbose. You can see https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Automatic_transformation_of_XML_namespaces for the big problem I am solving.

Comment: Regarding your question, I find it unclear. Regarding your goal of "transformation of XML namespaces", isn't that already doable with XSLT?

Comment: @dagnelies XSLT is one of many engines my transformations use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I've found a good solution of my problem:

Because we have only two priorities: "preferred" and "non-preferred", the priority queue can be easily implemented as two queues: "preferred" and "non-preferred". In the usual (`next()`) traversal order, we will look first into preferred and then if it is empty non-preferred queue. If we need `next2()` traversal order, then instead look into non-preferred queue only.